# Git remove commits between branches

Tags: git

I have the following history in Git:

```
(master) A - B - C
                  \
(dev)              D - E - F - G - H - I
```

I would like to create something like this:

```
(master) A - B - C
                 | \
(patch_1)        |- E' - G' (G' shouldn't contain the changes happened at F commit)
(patch_2)        |- D' - F' (F' shouldn't contain the changes happened at E commit)
(dev)            |- D - E - F - G - H - I
```

Is it possible to create something like this?
If it is not possible what is better from the following option:
1. Rewrite the code from the beginning?
2. Squash all these commits into one with a "nice" and big commit message?

Comment: What about (H - I) commits in patch_1, patch_2 branches??

Comment: I don't want them to be present at patch_1, patch_2 branches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I can think of is using git cherry-pick.

1. Change to dev branch, get SHA-1 commits of E, G, D and F (using git log --oneline).
2. From master branch, create patch_1 branch and issue git cherry-pick command with SHA-1 of E, G (as arguments).
3. From master branch, create patch_2 branch and issue git cherry-pick command with SHA-1 of D, F (as arguments).

Comment: I started to use git not for a long time ago. When I cherry-pick F commit, I would get the changes happened at E commit or not?

Comment: @user1562655 `cherry-pick` can actually be used for multiple commits. It even accepts commit ranges as an argument.